# Md tabs with ng-hide - keep the previously selected tab active

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-material

I'm working with a set of tabs in which there are tabs that are to be hidden and shown dynamically.

The problem is that when a tab goes from being hidden to visible, it becomes the selected tab. I wish for the previously selected tab to still be selected after tabs are shown.

Here's a simple example. In this case, if "Three" is selected, and I hit the button to show the "Two" tab, I want "Three" to still be selected.

https://jsfiddle.net/b5aw533a/2/

Here's an example of how I tried using `md-active` to achieve this

https://jsfiddle.net/pspL9c7s/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `$scope.selectedTab` is equal to 2, which is the index of the selected tab.

When you add a new tab, then you should updated `$scope.selectedTab` accordingly.

Basically if you add a tab before the selected one, you should increment the index of the selected tab with `$scope.selectedTab++`. If the new tab comes after, then you don't have to.

```
$scope.showTab = function() {
  // we add a tab before, so we update the index of the selected one
  $scope.selectedTab++;
  $scope.shouldShow = true;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v8jL75tf/

Comment: That still raises the question though: why `md-autoselect="false"` doesn't do a thing? If this counts as adding a new tab, one should be able to add that directive and expect it to work, but clearly it doesn't.

Comment: I don't hink `autoselect` is involved here: you have an index that the directive assume to be the selected tab with `md-selected`. If you change the array, the index don't refer to the same items of the array.

Comment: Right, but in that case `autoselect` is never involved. I mean.. there is always a selected index. `autoselect` should exactly do what @Dallin asked for imo, or the docs should be updated. (I'm not nitpicking here, I'm just a bit confused.)

Comment: @floribon What happens when you have the first tab selected? With your solution it then selects the second tab. https://jsfiddle.net/cz85smd8/1/

Comment: @Dallin that's why I said that it depends if you add a tab before or after the selected... If you add it after, then don't increment. You should know where you add a tab when you do so.

Comment: @floribon Your jsfiddle didn't reflect that but I see what you're saying.